# where does openwrt store time ? How does it store the time?

Tags: openwrt

I have device which has openwrt. Lets say time in device is 3:00pm and then I remove power. If I attach power again at 3:15pm it still has 3:00pm time. I know it doesnt have RTC to update time but where it stores time as 3:00 pm ? What is the file location ?

Comment: I believe OpenWRT periodically updates your router's time form the internet using NTP. Once it receives the latest time from a remote server, this data is stored in nvram until the next update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System date and time are set by `/etc/init.d/sysfixtime` script by finding the most recent timestamp of any file found in `/etc`:

```
boot() {
    local curtime="$(date +%s)"
    local maxtime="$(find /etc -type f -exec date -r {} +%s \; | sort -nr | head -n1)"
    [ $curtime -lt $maxtime ] && date -s @$maxtime
}
```

Then, if you have Internet connection, NTP client will receive the actual date and time from an NTP server configured in `/etc/config/system`

Comment: This answer solved an irregular problem I was having with my router where it would randomly stop giving out addresses after a reboot.  Oddly, most often a cold reboot would "fix" the problem.

I had a ton of files on the system that had their times set to 2035.  Touching those and rebooting seems to have fixed this once and for all.